# Does a Ring of Mind Shielding affect the dream spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, languages, telepathy

The party warlock recently acquired a *[ring of mind shielding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-mind-shielding)* in *Tales from the Yawning Portal*

> The altar to the Elder Elemental God in the Steading of the Hill Giant Chief

The party patron is a spellcaster who is in a city distant from them.  She is about to contact them via the spell *[Dream](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dream)* for an update on their progress in resolving the mission she has set them upon, and does not know about the *ring*.  She wants a much longer conversation than *sending* would allow, but has not used *dream* before to contact them and they do not know that she is planning to do so.

*Dream* is a 5th level illusion spell, and will allow her to contact the party as follows:

> If the target is asleep, the messenger appears in the target’s dreams and can converse with the target as long as it remains asleep, through the duration of the spell.

Note that the contact is automatic and there is no saving throw, so long as she does not use the spell to attack the target with a nightmare.

The *ring* says that

> Creatures can telepathically communicate with you only if you allow it.

**Will the *ring* protect against the automatic contact from the spell?**

If the warlock **can** use the *ring* to decide whether or not to 'receive the call' while he sleeps, will he know who the sender is, or who the sender is purporting to be, before he makes this decision?

**For me**, the answer hinges on how I should understand "telepathically" in this description, as the **natural English meaning** of 'communicating feeling at a distance' which could include the *Dream* spell, or as a **specific term** that applies only to abilities specifically using the word *telepathy*, such as various feats, spells, and creature languages.  Thus, an answer able to clarify this would be particularly helpful to me.  However, any answer that resolves the question is welcome.

Related: [Is the Telepathy rule in the Monster Manual only applicable to monster telepathy abilities?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113593/is-the-telepathy-rule-in-the-monster-manual-only-applicable-to-monster-telepathy)

Comment: related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179471/

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Tagged in the natural English sense of including the word telepathy in their description.  However, removed by edit to hopefully make less confusing.

Comment: To be sure this isn't an XY Problem, are you sure you're actual question is "is telepathy a game term", or is your actual concern something like "does the ring of mind shielding protect against the *dream* spell"?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov  Whether the ring offers protection is my proximate concern and reason for asking the question.  For me, that hinges on what the word 'telepathically' means, but to the extent that is not true for others, could be indicative of an XY problem and I will retitle the question.  I would like to be able to apply the 'lesson learned' from the answer here to future questions, but I am (admittedly slowly) realizing that this site discourages such generalization.

Comment: I understand the "teach a man to fish" motivation here, but I think there is a faulty underlying assumption that teaching you to fish for carp will adequately equip you to fish for marlin. There is nothing wrong with asking a question about *dream*, and then when you have trouble with another spell or feature, asking a new question about that one.

Comment: Looks good now, I've upvoted.

Comment: If the question is now just about whether a Ring of Mind Shielding blocks a Dream spell, I think it's a dupe of this one: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168768/40516

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson That question definitely addresses part of mine - my search did not find it, and I appreciate you bringing it to my attention.  However, it is not a complete duplicate as it does not address my contingent question "If the warlock can use the ring to decide whether or not to 'receive the call' while he sleeps, will he know who the sender is, or who the sender is purporting to be, before he makes this decision?"  That question also makes an assumption about what 'telepathically' means, but does not explicitly defend that assumption, which was something I had hoped to elicit.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson I'm not sure whether I should edit / petition for this to re-open, or ask the contingent question as a separate post.

Comment: Given that there aren't any answers, you can definitely update your question to what you're looking for specifically now. It does sound like the crux of this is whether or not the Ring of Mind Shielding also acts as a answering service for telepathic communication, right? If so, then [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115492/how-can-you-gain-selective-protection-from-sending) is somewhat related.